# Command to get the hostname of remote server using IP address

Tags: 12.04, networking, command-line

I want to get the hostname of a remote server using the IP address using my Ubuntu.

In Windows we can get using NBTSTAT but this doesn't work in Linux.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## NetBIOS

Windows (and Linux devices with Samba) use NetBIOS to 'publish' their addresses. This is what `NBTSTAT` uses to look up the IP address.

To find a hostname in your local network by IP address you can use:

```
nmblookup -A <ip>
```

Or you can install `nbtscan` by running:

```
sudo apt-get install nbtscan
```

And use:

```
nbtscan <ip>
```

## Multicast DNS

If systems publish their address via Multicast DNS (OS X, Windows 10 and Linux devices with a running `avahi-daemon` do this), do a lookup using `avahi-resolve` (requires installing `avahi-utils`):

```
avahi-resolve -a <ip>
```

## Reverse DNS

If the host has a public IP-address and a working reverse DNS entry, use the `dig` (requires installing `dnsutils`) or `host` (requires installing `bind9-host`) programs:

```
dig -x <ip>
host <ip>
```

Comment: it said no reply from xxx.xx.xx.xxx but ping is able to communicate with server

Comment: In that case, try `host`.

Comment: ok now i used host ipaddress, It replied Host xxx.xx.xx.xxx.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Comment: Is the server in your local network or is it a public IP address?

Comment: Yes this is in our local Network.

Comment: In that case the first command should work. I have no idea why it doesn't. I'll add another option to my answer.

Comment: Might have its own firewall on it blocking pings.  I know my machines are configured that way.

Comment: If samba is not installed on remote node, nmblookup is useless. :)

Comment: @alfred: true, added that information along with information on MDNS.

Answer (score 10):

Simply type the following command into the Linux/Ubuntu terminal:

```
host <ip>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another minor addition to others contribution, in case you don't know the IP.

If you don't know your  then type:

```
sudo ifconfig -all
```

You may find the  there. Then, all you need to do is use the:

```
 host <ip>
```

command as mentioned before.

Although this is a already answered question, I may found useful add this simple hint to ubuntu-linux newcomers.